# Error in custom Admin menu controller - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I created a **custom menu** but **got this error**.

> Fatal error: Class News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News contains
>   1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute)
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento3\app\code\News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php
>   on line 12

these are the codes

**News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php**

```
<?php 
namespace News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use News\LatestNews\Model\NewsFactory;

abstract class News extends Action
{
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry;

/**
 * Result page factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

/**
 * News model factory
 *
 * @var \News\LatestNews\Model\NewsFactory
 */
protected $_newsFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
 */
public function __construct(Context $context,
    Registry $coreRegistry,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    NewsFactory $newsFactory
) {
   parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
}

/**
 * News access rights checking
 *
 * @return bool
 */
    protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return         $this->_authorization->isAllowed('News_LatestNews::manage_news');
}
}
```

**News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News\Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

use News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

class Index extends News
{
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
  if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
        $this->_forward('grid');
        return;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('News_LatestNews::main_menu');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple News'));

    return $resultPage;
   }
}
```

**News\LatestNews\Block\Adminhtml\News\News.php**

```
<?php

namespace News\LatestNews\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container;

class News extends Container
{
   /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
   protected function _construct()
      {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_news';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'News_LatestNews';
        $this->_headerText = __('Manage News');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add News');
        parent::_construct();
      }
   }
```

**News\LatestNews\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="News_LatestNews::main_menu" title="Simple News" 
            module="News_LatestNews" sortOrder="20" 
            resource="News_LatestNews::simplenews" />
        <add id="News_LatestNews::add_news" title="Add News" 
            module="News_LatestNews" sortOrder="1" parent="News_LatestNews::main_menu" 
            action="simplenews/news/new" resource="News_LatestNews::manage_news" />
        <add id="News_LatestNews::manage_news" title="Manage News" 
            module="News_LatestNews" sortOrder="2" parent="News_LatestNews::main_menu" 
            action="simplenews/news/index" resource="News_LatestNews::manage_news" />
        <add id="News_LatestNews::configuration" title="Configurations" 
            module="News_LatestNews" sortOrder="3" parent="News_LatestNews::main_menu" 
            action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/simplenews" 
            resource="News_LatestNews::configuration" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

**News\LatestNews\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="simplenews" frontName="simplenews">
            <!-- <module name="Tutorial_SimpleNews" /> -->
            <module name="News_LatestNews" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**News\LatestNews\etc\acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="News_LatestNews::simplenews" title="Simple News" 
                sortOrder="100">
                <resource id="News_LatestNews::add_news" title="Add News" 
                    sortOrder="1" />
                <resource id="News_LatestNews::manage_news" title="Manage News" 
                    sortOrder="2" />
                <resource id="News_LatestNews::configuration" title="Configurations" 
                    sortOrder="3" />
            </resource> 

            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="News_LatestNews::config" title="News Configuration" sortOrder="50" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
      </resource>       
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

**News\LatestNews\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="News_LatestNews" setup_version="1.0.2" active="true">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Edit:**

```
1 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
      0 => true,
      1 => 1,
      2 => 'true',
      3 => '1',
      4 => false,
      5 => 0,
      6 => 'false',
      7 => '0',
    )
```

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` run & check

Comment: delete \var\generation folder and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self-explained. `\News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News` extends from abstract class `Magento\Backend\App\Action` which implements `Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute()`. So, in your custom controller class need to have `execute()` method.

Or, `\News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News` is an abstract class.

Comment: in News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News\Index.php there is an execute method which is extended in News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News ,
is it wrong?

Comment: @enjames `News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News` should be an abstract class. So, you don't need to declare the `execute` method in this class. Your index controller will extend from it and declare `execute` method .

Comment: O got a new error 
`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)`

i just add abstract
abstract class News extends Action,

Comment: @enjames you can update your question with the new code lines?

Comment: You tried to `var_dump()` what? You tried to use `var_dump` and then show the new error?

Comment: var_dump($this->_authorization->isAllowed('News_LatestNews::manage_news'))  
in public function _isAllowed()

Comment: Yeah! I think you should open new question  which related to the new issue. I think it's a different issue.