# Magento 2 Custom module admin controller error

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, custom

I have created the custom module as per the below tutorial:

http://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html

And after I am getting the below error:

> Fatal error: Class Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News contains
>   1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute)
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento3\app\code\Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php
>   on line 12

After that I have done some google and found the solution for the `execute()` function in below answer:

[Error in custom Admin menu controller - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160407/error-in-custom-admin-menu-controller-magento-2?answertab=votes#tab-top)

According to the answer I have changed the class name from class to abstract class.

After that I am getting the below error:

```
Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)
```

**Please see below is the Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php file code:**

```
<?php

namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

abstract class News extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
     const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'News_LatestNews::‌​manage_news';

     /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * News model factory
     *
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
     */
    protected $_newsFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        NewsFactory $newsFactory
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
    }


}
```

**Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News\Index.php file code:**

```
<?php

namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

class Index extends News
{

    /**
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute()
    {
      if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
            $this->_forward('grid');
            return;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Tutorial_SimpleNews::main_menu');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple News'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

I have done the `var_dump($this->_authorization->isAllowed('News_LatestNews::‌​manage_news'));` also it's output it `bool(true)`.

Anybody, can help me how I can trace this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you already have your module `Tutorial_SimpleNews` created and enabled in your store.

I've run this code on M2.1.3.

**1/** In `app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/etc/adminhtml/` folder create an `routes.xml` file with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="news" id="news">
            <module name="Tutorial_SimpleNews" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**2/** In `app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/etc/` folder create an `acl.xml` file with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news" title="New" sortOrder="10" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**3/** In `app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/etc/adminhtml/` folder create an `menu.xml` file with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news"
             title="News"
             module="Tutorial_SimpleNews"
             sortOrder="1"
             resource="Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news"
             action="news/news"
        />
    </menu>
</config>
```

**4**/ In `app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/` folder create `News.php` file with this code:

```
<?php

namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

abstract class News extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
     const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news';

     /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
}
```

**5/** In `app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News/` folder create `Index.php` file with this code:

```
<?php

namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

class Index extends News
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
    */
    public function execute()
    {
      if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
            $this->_forward('grid');
            return;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Tutorial_SimpleNews::main_menu');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple News'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**6/** Make sure the role your are accessing your admin let you access this action

**7/** In your Magento root directory, run commands:

`rm -rf var/cache/*`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**8/** Open your browser and access your Magento admin (logged out if you were logged in before), you will see a new menu entry on the left with a link to your controller called "News".

Comment: I have added the `const` as per your answer but still getting same error.

Comment: Then can you remove protected method `_isAllowed` in abastract class News please?
Can you also show the code of your Index Class in your question please?

Comment: I have removed the protected method `_isAllowed` method and added the Index Class code.

Comment: @mageDev0688 check my updated answer please.

Comment: I have gone through you updated answer, but I am getting same error. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Can you print the whole error in your question please?

Comment: Please see the whole error screenshot [link](http://prntscr.com/eeeyla)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated Index class as per your updated answer, but the issue is same. I think I need to follow another tutorial, I am beginner in Magento 2 and learning my self.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please do it from scratch.

Comment: I have updated the files as per your updated answer, it's showing blank screen and not loading the Grid in the admin, Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: You have to add `$_newsFactory` related code in `News.php`and create `Grid.php` class like in your tutorial ...

Comment: Added the `$_newsFactory` according to the tutorial and created the `Grid.php` class but not any success.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is 1.5 years old. Things have changed since then.

Make your class `News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News` as abstract and you should be ok.

You need to do that because all classes that extend the abstract controller need to have a method called `execute` that is the actual method that handles the request.
Since you are never instantiating your class you can make it abstract and the classes that extend your class need to contain the `execute` method.

Comment: I have added the `excute()` function. Please check the updated Controller file.

Comment: `execute()` method should be in your Index class not in Abstract.

Comment: I have added the `execute()` function in the index class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check and change your XML on `adminhtnl/layout -> simplenews_news_grid_block.xml`

```
<argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">
      Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection
</argument>
<argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
<argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
<argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="boolean">           true</argument>
```

to

```
<argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection</argument>
<argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
<argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
<argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
```

no space before and after value `>value <`